# Value network diverges when used asynchronously in A3C implementation

Tags: python, asynchronous, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

My code is an implementation of the A3C Deep Reinforcement Learning algorithm based on Grokking Deep Reinforcement Learning book and implementation from Miguel Morales.
I use the `CartPole-v1` environment. I build a value network that I use for both VPG and A3C. In VPG it works as expected.
In A3C I create a `work` method where I have 8 workers working asynchronously with the help of pytorch's/python's multiprocessing library.

```
workers = [mp.Process(target=self.work, args=(rank,)) for rank in range(self.n_workers)]
[w.start() for w in workers]; [w.join() for w in workers]
```

I pass the value network in the class as a function `self.value_model_fn = value_model_fn` and on the `work` method I create local value networks to work with `local_value_model = self.value_model_fn(nS)` where `nS` is the state size. I do the exact same thing for a policy network but the policy network works as expected both in VPG and A3C.
I also load a shared policy and value model that I initialize in the `train` function like this:

```
        local_policy_model = self.policy_model_fn(nS, nA)
        local_policy_model.load_state_dict(self.shared_policy_model.state_dict())
        local_value_model = self.value_model_fn(nS)
        local_value_model.load_state_dict(self.shared_value_model.state_dict())
```

When I run `local_value_model(state)` the code gets in a never ending loop.

I tried running the value network outside the `work` method and it works fine. I tried running it without loading the `shared_value_network` and I also tried running it before the `local_policy_network` but it just doesn't work when I run it inside the `work` method. 
What it should do is return a value in this form: `tensor([[0.0214]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>` but instead it loops forever.
I don't really know what other direction to take, I don't think there'a a problem in the network implementation since it works fine outside the work method AND the VPG implemetation so my guess is there's something about the multiprocessing that makes it diverge.